# Submit form and get echo from php in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, forms, form-submit

I have a [form](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) and a [submit button](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)
that sends some [input](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) values
per [POST](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) to a php file. The php validates and echos a value.
How can I handle this echo value per jquery (in a jquery function)?

Sample code:

```
        <form id="login" method="post" action="/php/login.php">
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" autofocus="true"></input>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></input>
            <button id="loginButton" type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
```

just pretend /php/login.php is

```
<?php
    echo "OK";
?>
```

now, I imagine there must be a way to get this echo value in some sort of a form-submit callback in jquery?

Comment: This might help: [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: do you have any code of your own to show?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out that I had to elude the actual submit and do a seperate post

```
$("#login").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var myUsername = … 
    var myPassword = …
     $.post("/php/login.php", { username:myUsername, password:myPassword }, function(data){
         alert(data); // which is the php echo.
    });

});
```